# setContentView R.layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having a problem that R.layout is not defined can anyone help? As you can see I am not importing r.layout as been suggested in other answers to this obviously common problem. I have check all existing comments but no suggestions solve my error.

```
package com.tom;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button new_proj, open_proj;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new_proj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNew);
        open_proj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOpen);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
}
```

Comment: you tried to import `com.tom.R;` ?

Comment: Check if the R file is generated. If it's not, there might be an error  in one of your resource files.

Comment: Sometimes a simple Project --> Clean will even clear this up. Just make sure your project is checked.

Comment: How do I know if the R file is being generated?

Comment: @user2035391 - Check the `gen` folder for the `R.java` file

Comment: Ok I haven't got a R.java file is there anyway I can check the resource file for errors?

Answer (score 1):

if you think you have the current code but also it has the R error then first clean the project through project-> clean the build it. after it if you have correct code it must retain R. even doing this doesnot solve then it is sure that you have done the code which is not supported here. so better undo the previous things to the place where you were correct before.

Eg once in my project ,i lost the R while trying to place the flv file. later i knew that it supports only mp3. such errors can cause such problems

Answer (score 0):

Within your source-file, `Shift-Ctrl-O` (Mac: `Shift-Command-O`) will add required import and remove unnecessary ones. If that doesn't address it, look in the Problems tab to see if one of the `XML` files is broken.

Comment: All this done is added import android.R; to the top of the file. However it still doesn't work

Comment: Does `activity_main.xml` exist in your `res/layout` folder?